# learning about database performance: php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, normalization

I'm developing a kind of a bidding site, and keeping the item up for bid (and its details) in one table, and the bids in another.

As a matter of principle, to indicate winning bids (for retrieving history, etc), it is better to:

1. Store a column in the items table called bidWon, and storing the bid ID there, then retrieving it that way?
2. Storing a column in the bid table saying "status" or something, and attaching there the item id IF the bid is successful; otherwise leaving that column empty and then querying database with the NOT IN "winning" or whatever.
3. Both, for quick pulling via item or bid table (and using a JOIN or something to get all appropriate data).
4. ??? Something I haven't thought of?

I am asking this question broadly as I enter the next level of db programming and want to prevent performance issues at outset.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're likely to get "lots" of bids, and each auction will only ever have one winner (?), you'd be better off storing the ID of the winning bid in the auction table. That'd cost you one "whatever" (int? varchar) worth of data per auction, rather than one 'whatever' per bid, of which almost all of those whatevers would get wasted.

Comment: And then if I wanted to list losing "bids" for a particular customer, I'd query the bids table based on 1) userID, and 2) the bidID NOT being attached to any item?

Comment: Technically, for any given auction, ALL except one bid will be losers. Grab all the bids, and if the LAST bid is the same as the user in question, it's a winner and can be excluded.

Comment: Thanks! One wrench is that its not automatically the highest bidder (so I can't automagically sort) but I think you've given me the initiative to start...